# Identify this burnt SMD component marked QA / RA14

Tags: diodes, identification, components, surface-mount

[image]

I hope to repair a PCB for a hard disk drive which has a burnt out SMD component. It has a connection at each end, with a polarity(?) line at one end. It has "ON" in a circle, and "QA" and "RA 14." written on it.

I have searched on line with no success. Can anyone identify this component?

Comment: Please add a good photograph of the part on the PCB - we need to see it and have some contact for what you are trying to repair. But it does sound like a Diode by "ON semiconductor".

Comment: https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/ONSM/ONSMS15066/ONSMS15066-1.pdf?hkey=52A5661711E402568146F3353EA87419 is my best guess based on the information provided

Comment: That component did not burn without a reason. Most likely the reason is that there is a problem elsewhere in the circuit and replacing the diode will make it burn again and thus replacing it will not make it work.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/568325/identify-component-from-hard-drive-pcb). However since I got the accepted answer on that one, I (as a mod) should not close *this* one as a duplicate of *that* one, as that could be perceived as a "conflict of interest". However, if others agree, I recommend closing this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @SamGibson Recommend putting more information, such as the "QA" code, into the title of that previous question then, so people searching might actually find it.

Comment: @Unimportant - Good point, I will do that. In fact the question I linked *is* shown in the search results using just the search term "QA", but much lower as that is only in the text, not (yet) in the title. I also found the same question has also been asked & answered [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244508/please-identify-this-burnt-out-smd-component). That answer is mine too, so I've not realized the duplication, and answered it twice myself! :-( I'll have to figure out how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a ON-semiconductor  [NSA5.0AT3G](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/NSA5.0A-D-101770.pdf). Device specific code "QA".